# How do I disconnect two points of a bezier curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am fairly new to Blender and I would love some help with this problem. I modeled a bezier curve a couple of days ago, and then wanted to change it.

I know how to connect two vertices of a bezier curve by pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to fill it, but how unfill two vertices, such as to disconnect them?

Here are some pictures to help out with my scenario. Picture 1 shows the two vertices I want to fill. Picture 2 shows both the vertices I wish to disconnect. Thanks!

P.s. What is this red line that showed on my curve? (picture 2)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can select two or more consecutive vertex and press `X` to delete a segment between them. Red line seems to be just an additional separate segment of your cruve

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To close a curve (make it Cyclic), select the first and last segments and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

To open a closed curve at the press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again.

To open a curve at any point that is not the start and end of the loop, select two control points and press Delete (or <kbd>X</kbd>) and select **Delete Segment**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a "control point"? Because when I tried that, I couldn't control where a gap would open.

Comment: As an addition it's possible to select any control point of the curve in order to make it cyclic with Alt+C. Selecting all control points will make cyclic all the curves of the edited curve object.

Comment: Luke: First, a control point is the center vertex of the line with three vertices not part of the actual curve (in answer above they're pink/red), the center vertex of the three is chosen to select that control point. A segment deleted with 'x' [delete] is the one between any two adjacent control points.  This is all done in edit mode.

To have more than two control points, you must have [extruded] additional curves from the end point of bezier curve either when creating the curve, or in edit mode and extruding.