# Fixing SVG Paths

Tags: bezier-curves, svg

I have imported a floor plan (SVG) into Blender. Upon close inspection the paths that I created are no longer connected and are "Curve" objects how can I fix these quickly? Please provide reference links and keyboard shortcuts if possible.

Thank you,
Isaiah

[image]

Comment: in object mode press `Ctrl` `Alt` `Shift` `C` then choose "Mesh from curve"

Comment: you can directly import autocad file in blender why svg

Comment: @atek I don't have autocad, this is a free / low cost venture for me.

Comment: If comment of David did not work then plz attach the file let see how we can help u in more details

Comment: Don't needlessly convert to mesh if you don't need to, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56344/reducing-internal-faces-generated-by-extensive-curve-extrusion for a few cleanup techniques

Comment: David, thank you I learned that on windows its Alt C that pulls up the dialog window for "Mesh from curve". Unfortunately it gives me a bunch of segments lines which is not desirable. I would like to have on shape or path. Is there a step missing to reach that point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent to Remove Doubles for Bezier curves?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32355/is-there-an-equivalent-to-remove-doubles-for-bezier-curves)

Comment: Thank you all for the support and references it's immensely appreciated. I will provide a link to the resource a little but later as I am away from my comp at the moment.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82794/how-do-i-disconnect-two-points-of-a-bezier-curve/82795#82795

Answer (score 1):

When importing paths as SVGs different paths are imported as different curves.

To make different curves into a single one: In **Object Mode** Select the curves (use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select multiple objects)

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to **Join**

From The [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/introduction.html#join)**.

> Join merges all selected objects into the last selected Active object. All object data is linked to the active object (which must be selected). All objects must be of the same type: mesh, curve, surface or armature. If several curves are joined, each one will keep its subtype (NURBS or Bézier).

Comment: I tried this with no resolve.

Comment: Are you in object mode?

Comment: No, I was in edit mode but just in case I will try it again.

Comment: @MrZak indeed!... fixed